How to call useFactory from within forRootAsync of a dynamic module?
I am trying to create a DynamicModule that will return different providers based on config value from ConfigService, but I am struggling to see how I can fetch that config from within the forRootAsync of my module. Top level code looks somehow line below.
App module
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: [configuration],
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    PrometheusModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => ({
        enableMetrics: config.get('telemetry.enableMetrics'),
        counters: [httpRequestCounter],
        histograms: [httpRequestDuration],
      }),
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {}

PrometheusModule:
export interface PrometheusMopduleOpts {
  enableMetrics: boolean;
  counters: client.CounterConfiguration<string>[];
  histograms: client.HistogramConfiguration<string>[];
}

export interface PrometheusModuleAsyncOpts
  extends Pick<ModuleMetadata, 'imports'> {
  useFactory: (
    ...args: any[]
  ) => Promise<PrometheusMopduleOpts> | PrometheusMopduleOpts;
  inject: any[];
}

const defaultOpts: PrometheusMopduleOpts = {
  enableMetrics: false,
  counters: [],
  histograms: [],
};

@Global()
@Module({})
export class PrometheusModule {
  static forRoot(opts: PrometheusMopduleOpts = defaultOpts): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: PrometheusModule,
      imports: opts.enableMetrics
        ? []// process opts.histograms & opts.counters
        : [],
      providers: opts.enableMetrics
      ? []// process opts.histograms & opts.counters
      : [],
      exports: ['METRICS_HOLDER'],
    };
  }

  static async forRootAsync(
    asyncOpts: PrometheusModuleAsyncOpts
  ): Promise<DynamicModule> {
    const opts = await asyncOpts.useFactory(); // <=== this will obviously return undefined!
    return PrometheusModule.forRoot(opts);
  }
}

The issue is now that await asyncOpts.useFactory(); call within forRootAsync will throw as it doesn't have ConfigService passed into it. Is there a way to get that config in there? Or am I doing this the wrong way around?

The config is not accessible there but it can be injected in the providers. You could reorganize the code around that. Or you could sacrifice simplicity of the config and convert it into a bunch of forCounter static method calls, that would, for example, register instances of CounterConsumer for each object in opts.counters (you get the idea). It all depends on how exactly you're treating that config.
